# Prism Unity - EventAggregator hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

i have a problem with EventAggregator, on how make it work, i show a sample application where i have 4 projects:

-Shell
-Module 'Order'
-Module 'Customer'
-Module 'Customer references'
-Shared (global event aggregator)

Assume that i want to add a new Order, inside my order form (Module.Order) i have a combobox with customers, and a button that open another form to create a customer (Module.Customer) and i want that when i create my customer, the combobox inside the order form reload

I can manage this with that

OrderForm

```
   private void AddCustomerExecute(object Dialog)
    {
        DialogVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        _unityContainer.RegisterInstance<string>("RegionName", M_G_O_ListModule._RegionDialog);

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UIX_GlobalEvent.PassParameter>().Subscribe(ReloadCustomers);

        _moduleManager.LoadModule("M_T_S_CustomersModule");

        _shellService.ShowDialogUser(M_G_O_ListModule._RegionDialog, "M_T_S_CustomersModule_Add");
    }
```

CustomerForm

```
    private void SaveExecute()
    {
        Customer.CustomerCollection.LogAdded = DateTime.Now;
        Customer.CustomerCollection.LogUserID = _userCompany.User.UserID;

        _customerRepository.InsertCollection(Customer.CustomerCollection);

        _shellService.CloseDialogUser(_regionName, M_T_S_CustomersModule._viewAdd);

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<UIX_GlobalEvent.PassParameter>().Publish(Customer.CustomerCollection.CustomerID);
    }
```

The problem is when from the CustomerForm, i want to add a Reference (Module.CustomerReference) because, if i use the same process, when i save the CustomerReference it reload the combobox inside the order form, because the global event is subscribed

Someone know how can i manage this?
Thank you

Comment: You already have an `PassParameter` event, which reloads the `OrderForm` I would just make a second `PubSubEvent` for the `CustomerForm` It's a different event, and it's not against the rules to have a method fire off multiple `Publish()`s. But I may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to restate the question so I make sure I understood it properly. Bear with me.

You have a Customer Form, (`Modules.Customer`) in which you can both 1) Add a new Customer and 2) Add a new Customer Reference.

When you create a new Customer, it fires an Event (`UIX_GlobalEvent.PassParameter>().Publish()`)

Both `Modules.Orders` and `Modules.CustomerReference` subscribe to this event.

So your problem is, when you use add a new Customer Reference, that global event tells your `Module.Orders` to reload the combo box containing the `Customers` and you don't want that behavior.

Is that correct? If so...

---

You should not need to 'reload' your combo boxes. That should be the job of data binding and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model. 
Check out the `ViewModelBase` base class included with Prism Library.

When `SaveExecute()`; is called on the CustomerForm, you add the `Customer` to the `CustomerCollection`. And it fires a global event.

In your `OrderView`, Your ComboBox should be bound to an `ObservableCollection<Customer>` defined in your `OrderViewModel` (**Or `ObservableDictionary<int, string>`, you shouldn't really store the entire Customer)

In your `OrderViewModel` in the global event handler you should:

1. Receive the CustomerID (The payload from the event)
2. Look up the Customer from the repository by it's ID.
3. Add the Customer to the `ObservableCollection<Customer>`

---

How this solves your problem:

When you add a new `CustomerReference` (I'm assuming the `Customer` must already exist.) and your `OrderViewModel` receives the event, you can check if the `Customer` exists in the `CustomerCollection`, and if it does exist, the `CustomerCollection` is not changed, and your combo box will not 'reload'.

Also, When you add a new Customer, it's only asking for 1 customer by Id, instead of *all* customers to update your ComboBox.

---

### UPDATE

Let's use the new simplified example provided from the comments and apply the same logic as above.

```
public class OrdersViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IProductsDataProvider _dataProvider;
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _productsComboBox;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsComboBox 
    { 
        get { return _productsComboBox; }
        set { _productsComboBox = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public OrdersViewModel(IProductsDataProvider dataProvider, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
    {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<GlobalUIX.ProductCreatedEvent>().Subscribe(OnProductCreatedEventHandler);
    }

    public void Initialize() 
    {
        //Logic to load combo box with data from the database
        var products = _dataProvider.GetAllProducts();
        ProductsComboBox.AddRange(products);
    }

    private void OnProductCreatedEventHandler(int eventPayloadProductId) 
    {
        var isProductInComboBox = ProductsComboBox.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == eventPayloadProductId);

        if (isProductInComboBox == null) {      
            var existingProduct = _dataProvider.GetProductById(eventPayloadProductId);
            ProductsComboBox.Add(newProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

### Order of Operations

1. ViewModel is constructed when `OrdersModule` is instantiated.
2. ViewModel takes in an `IProductsDataProvider`, which is this ViewModels gateway to the database in the Data Access layer.
3. The ComboBox is initialized with an empty `ObservableCollection()`;
4. OrdersModule calls the `Load()` method to initialize the combo box from products from the database (Really, this should just be a `Dictionary<int, string>()` so you don't load the entire Product)
5. `_eventAggregator` subscribes to the `ProductCreatedEvent`
6. When `ProductCreatedEvent` fires, `OnProductCreatedEventHandler` is called..
7. If the item is already listed in the combo box, do nothing.
8. If the item is not listed in the combo box, add it.
9. `OnPropertyChanged();` is fired from the setter of `ProductsComboBox`
10. `INotifyPropertyChanged` tells the UI to update.

Duplicate this exactly for UnitsOfMeasureModule.

Which will give you 2 separate modules, that will each have a combo box that is updated from a single event, but does not reload the entire combo box when the event is fired.

Comment: Hi @Adam Vincent, i try to simplify with another sample, i have 3 different modules: OrdersModule/ProductsModule/UnitsOfMeasureModule from the view OrderCreate(OrdersModule) i have a button that call ProductCreate(ProductsModule) and from this i have a button that call UnitCreate(UnitsOfMeasureModule). OrderCreate have a combobox with Products and ProductCreate have a combobox with UnitsOfMeasure, so i when a call ProductCreate in OrderCreate i subscribe to a  GlobalEvent, and when i call UnitCreate i subscribe to the same event, so when i publish the event to reload Units in ProductCreate

Comment: It fire the reload of Products inside OrderCreate. Probably i have to create different GlobalEvents for any modules i have. It's right? Thank you

Comment: Check the update to the answer @MatteoBeretta and see if it makes more sense with a code example.

Comment: ok it make sense, so i have to create a global event for each, i can't use same global event, something like item_created_event. Right?

Comment: No, you absolutely can, and should use a single global event.  My answer shows that both `OrdersModule` and `UnitsOfMeasureModule` can handle the same global event without updating the combo box unless the combo box actually needs to be updated

Comment: If you have a Pluralsight account (or are eligible for the 10 day free trial), I can link the resource where I learned all this. Maybe someone else's take on it will help.

Comment: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-mvvm-test-driven-development-viewmodels/table-of-contents

Comment: Ok, but my problem is that in OrdersModule i have to reload Products,and in ProductsModule i have to reload Units

Comment: Another sample could be: Movie->Actor->ActorCountry

Answer (score 0):

You could forget eventaggregator entirely.
Register your observablecollection as singleton with unity.
or
Put it in application.current.resources if that doesn't suit for some reason.
One way or another, share the same observablecollection.
When you add in one window then it's the same collection bound in the other and you get the new customer there too.
or
You could add an event to whatever _customerrepository is so it says it's dirty to anything subscribing.
That then tells the subscriber to read the data again.

You have an awful lot of decoupling going on there.
If you don't really need it then the cost of the overhead created to make stuff work despite the decoupling is likely to exceeed the benefit.
Of course you might really need it and then you have no option.

Comment: You mean something like this   _unityContainer.RegisterInstance<ObservableCollection<Customers>>("CUSTOMERS"); and reuse this in the other module?

Comment: Yes. Observablecollection already has a collectionchanged event your view will automatically handle with the weak event pattern due to wpf binding.

Comment: Ok i'll try this way, bit Now i can't understand for what should i use eventagregator

Comment: Event aggregation/messaging is sometimes useful. Personally, I prefer MVVM light to PRISM. I rarely find all the complicated stuff in PRISM repays the effort.  Also, messenger is way easier to use than eventaggregator.

Comment: 1) Decoupling is never a bad thing. 2) Wrapping an `Observable` in a singleton is an anti-pattern to make a 'global'.  3) The `_customerRepository` most certainly should not be subscribing to a UI event. Stick with the event aggravator (misspelling on purpose, it is a bit painful to learn.)

Comment: My suggestion was the viewmodel subscribe to an event from the model - _customerRepository. Rather than an intermediate object. And anything which isn't necessary is wasted effort. If that then increases complexity and hence maintenance costs then it's doubly a bad thing. So decoupling can sometimes be bad. Especially if you already have something rather looks like it's going to be the same object to share. Or maybe that repository isn't actually a repository.

Comment: I will gladly provide some sources to back up my above points if you would like. However, providing an answer to a `EventAggragator ` question that is "Don't use `EventAggregator` because it's too complicated" is not an answer.